# Submenu click lists other dropdown

Tags: php, while-loop

I am working on a module where a part of my navigation menu has to come dynamically with associated dropdowns/submenus. It is like I have a table in my database `tbl_levels` where two LEVELS are kept. Under each LEVEL there are associated Units whose details are kept in another table `tbl_question_module` with `id` from `tbl_levels` as column `level`. I want these two levels to list one by one, which is I am getting. Now I want to list units associated with each level as drop down when LEVEL 1 or LEVEL 2 is clicked from navigation menu. I have implemented the below code but what I am obtaining is only submenus for LEVEL1 and when LEVEL 2 is clicked then it again opens up the LEVEL 1 list. Can I get some insight where I am getting wrong. This will be very helpful.

```
<?php

$sq_lev = $db->query("SELECT id,level_title from tbl_levels WHERE level_status = 1 ");
while($row_lev=mysql_fetch_array($sq_lev))  

{ 
$level_id=$row_lev['id'];
$level_title=$row_lev['level_title '];
?>           
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products3" class="collapsed"> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span><?php echo $level_title; ?><span class="arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products3">

<?php

$sq =   $db->query("SELECT id, title from tbl_question_module WHERE status = 1 AND level = $level_id ");
while($rowM=mysql_fetch_array($sq))

{  ?> 

<li><a href="studyMaterial.php?unit_id=<?php echo $fnc->encode($rowM['id']) ; ?>"><?php echo $rowM['title'] ; ?></a></li>

<?php  } ?> 

</ul> 
</li>  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Use mysql_free_result($sq); to free previous result after second while loop

Comment: Thanks for response. I ahve done this but its working only for 1st time loop only. Like its working only for LEVEL 1.

Comment: And still you are getting the same result?

Comment: $level_title is not defined in your code. Can you please define name first so we can identify you are getting more then one record in first query?

Comment: where can I place this mysql_free_result($sq); ? Inside the while loop?

Comment: Please check answer no need to add mysql_free_result($sq);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update `data-target` dynamically inside the loop

```
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products<?= $level_id ?>" class="collapsed"> <!-- **Changes here**  -->
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>
            <?php echo $level_title; ?>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products<?= $level_id ?>"> <!-- **Changes here**  -->
```

**ID** attribute of html is always unique in the current page. and according to `jquery` or `data-target` if more then two element contain the same id then it's always point to first element in the body